# Explicación sobre el proceso a seguir sobre este ejercicio

Tags: javascript, object, bucle-for

Estoy con un ejercicio que me esta comiendo la cabeza.
1º - Tengo un objeto con diferentes arrays dentro.
2º - Creo una función que le pasas como parametro una palabra
3º - El output debe ser las posición del key de cada letra de la palabra

```
var dictionary = {
    0: ['A', 'K', 'T', 'F', 'O', 'Y'],
    1: ['B', 'L', 'U', 'G', 'P', 'Z'],
    2: ['C', 'M', 'V', 'H', 'Q', '.'],
    3: ['D', 'N', 'W', 'I', 'R', ','],
    4: ['E', 'Ñ', 'X', 'J', 'S', ' ']
}
```

De la palabra HOLA su output seria 2010
Cada número seria la posición del key

No estoy buscando la solución ni el código entero. Solo entender como debería encarar el código y pasos a seguir, pero nada de código.
Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple: iteras por la palabra buscada; por cada letra, iteraras por el objeto, y, para cada elemento, compruebas si contiene o no la letra buscada:

```js
var dictionary = {
 0: ['A', 'K', 'T', 'F', 'O', 'Y'],
 1: ['B', 'L', 'U', 'G', 'P', 'Z'],
 2: ['C', 'M', 'V', 'H', 'Q', '.'],
 3: ['D', 'N', 'W', 'I', 'R', ','],
 4: ['E', 'Ñ', 'X', 'J', 'S', ' '],
};

function buscar( tabla, palabra ) {
 var indice = 0;
 var result = [];
 var inarray;

for( indice = 0; indice < palabra.length; ++indice )
 for( var idx in tabla ) {
  inarray = tabla[idx].indexOf( palabra[indice] );
  if( inarray != -1 ) result.push( idx );
 }

 return result.length ? result : undefined;
}

console.log( buscar( dictionary, 'HOLA' ) );
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias! @user87699